# Cannot find symbol getCurrentActivity when building an Android module for React-Native

Tags: java, android, react-native

[First of all, here is a test repo to replicate my issue](https://github.com/mmazzarolo/react-native-getactivity-test/)

Hello there,
I'm trying to create a simple Android module for React-Native and I'm having some trouble getting the current Activity from the Java code.

This is not the first native module I worked on, but I never had to obtain an Activity reference since today.

The [interested module](https://github.com/mmazzarolo/react-native-getactivity-test/blob/master/react-native-estimote-android/android/src/main/java/com/mmazzarolo/estimoteandroid/EstimoteAndroidModule.java) is a bridge to the Estimote SDK, but this is not relevant to the issue.
The module in Android studio works perfectly, but when I try to build it with `react-native run android` I get the following error:

```
:react-native-estimote-android:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
/Users/matteo/dev/react-native-example/react-native-estimote-android/android/src/main/java/com/mmazzarolo/estimoteandroid/EstimoteAndroidModule.java:64: error: cannot find symbol
        Activity currentActivity = this.getCurrentActivity();
                                       ^
  symbol: method getCurrentActivity()
1 error
:react-native-estimote-android:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

From my understanding extending **ReactContextBaseJavaModule** should be enough to grant me the usage of **this.getCurrentActivity()** (and Android studio agrees with me).

This is what I already tried to do:
- Implementing [ActivityEventListener](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html): same  **cannot find symbol** error when I try to import ActivityEventListener;
- android/.gradlew clean
- watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache clean && npm prune && npm i
- Tried the same repo on two different computers...

Any hints? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the issue was with the version of **react-native** in module **'react-native-estimote-android'**

Just change `compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.12.+'` to 
`compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'`

This will resolve the cannot find getCurrentActivity symbol.

**getCurrentActivity** method is not available in react-native 0.12 version. Thats why it was throwing error.

Comment: Its a bit late reply, but hope its useful to you

Answer (score 1):

```
 @ReactMethod
public void start(final Callback callback) {
    Activity currentActivity = getCurrentActivity();
    this.mBeaconManager.connect(new BeaconManager.ServiceReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceReady() {
            mBeaconManager.startRanging(region);
            callback.invoke();
        }
    });
}
```

Remove this from start method, if you do this.getCurrentActivity() it will referr to EstimoteAndroidModule context not to the app ReactContextBaseJavaModule context